# How to configure the zise tag when the device screen size is modified

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In xamarin I would like a label text with a maximum length. When they modify the size of the device screen, all the labels are not displayed correctly
I am using xamarin forms 5.0.0.2244

```
   var labelCountry = new Label
        {
            Text = $"Bienvenido a {Settings.Country} ",
            FontSize = 14,
            TextColor = Color.Blue
        };
```

Comment: please post the relevant code/xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the docs on [Layout Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options)

```
HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
```

this will make the `Label` expand to fill the size of it's parent container